# Why do I have to assign a function return (Array) to a variable before using it?

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, php-5.3

When the following line is reached:

```
$_SESSION['LOGIN'] = good_query_table($login_query)[0]["name"];
```

This error is printed:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in /srv/web/login.php on line 6
```

Attempting to find out what's wrong since this code has been running fine for years, I edited the code to first assign the function returned array to an array variable, then use it, which ran fine afterwards !

```
$arr = good_query_table( $login_quert );
$_SESSION['LOGIN'] = $arr[0]["name"];
```

The only new thing is that I'm now running the application on Ubuntu. It used to run for years on Windows.

- So why do I have to do that ?

Comment: [That only works on PHP 5.4+](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88)

Comment: Its called `Array dereferencing` btw

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP is each server running?

Function array de-referencing was added in 5.4.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php